# Multithreading: Output of changed object is not as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got two threads with the same job (increment the object's variable by one 50 times). Why do I get 2 and 2 as my first two outputs?

```
public class TestSyncTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                TestSync job = new TestSync();
                Thread a = new Thread(job);
                Thread b = new Thread(job);
                a.start();
                b.start();
        }
}

class TestSync implements Runnable {
        private int balance;


        public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                        increment();
                        System.out.println("balance is " + balance);

                }
        }

        public synchronized void increment() {
                int i = balance;
                balance = i + 1;
        }
}
```

I was expecting 1, 2, 3, ... not 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...

Comment: I know that I can make my run() method synchronized but the thing is I want my two threads work simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of asynchronous implementation. Namely, you print the value *independently* on `increment()`. In your particular case following happened. Thread A has incremented *balance* from 0 to 1. After the method `increment()` returned and before `println()` was called in thread A the method `increment()` was executed in thread B which incremented *balance* from 1 to 2. Then `println()` was called in one thread and printed 2. Then `println()` was called in another thread and printed 2.

Afterwards according to your output JVM has executed `increment()` and `println()` in each thread without interrupting for another thread. But it does  not mean that it will work in such way each time. Next time you execute it you can see more duplicating values (and correspondingly some other values missing).

If you want to see no duplicates, then you can put `println()` to the method `increment()`.

The execution in you particular *could* have been following:

- Thread A: increment(): 0 -> 1
- Thread B: increment(): 1 -> 2
- Thread A: println(): 2
- Thread B: println(): 2
- Thread A: increment(): 2 -> 3
- Thread A: println(): 3
- Thread B: increment(): 3 -> 4
- Thread B: println(): 4
  ...

I say *could* because many other scenarious could give the same result. For instance, incrementing from 2 to 5 could have been done by thread A, incrementing 5 to 6 in thread B, 6 to 10 in thread A, etc. If you print not only balance variable, but also thread ID, the result can be more interesting.

Comment: What is asynchronous implementation?

Comment: Asynchronous means that different pieces of code are being executed not one after another, but *independently* on each other. Here 2 threads are being executed independently on each other. The only piece of code that is *synchronous* is method *increment()*: When one of threads calls it, the other one is suspended and is waiting.